# Hbase table sizes on hdfs are X 4 of actual input file

Tags: hbase, hdfs

I'm new to this forum and hdfs/hbase.

I have created a table in hbase on hdfs. File loaded had 10Million record's with size of 1GB on windows disk. When file is loaded on hdfs, size of the table in hdfs is:-

```
root@narmada:~/agni/hdfs/hadoop-1.1.2# ./bin/hadoop fs -dus /hbase/hdfs_10M
hdfs://192.168.5.58:54310/hbase/hdfs_10M       4143809619
```

Can some one plz help to reduce the size?

table details.

```
DESCRIPTION                                                                                                  ENABLED
 'hdfs_10M', {NAME => 'v', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0',  true
 VERSIONS => '3', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => '2147483647', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'fa
 lse', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', ENCODE_ON_DISK => 'true', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
1 row(s) in 0.2340 seconds
```

Comment: I came here thinking I might get some answer.. :P

Answer (score 0):

Generally once when we load the file on top of HDFS it divides the file into blocks of equal size. By default this block size is 64mb. Hadoop maintains 3 duplicates of each block, that means if we want to store file of size 1TB on HDFS, we need a hardware to store 3TB. Each block will be stored on three different data nodes.

> Ref:http://hadooptutor.blogspot.com/2013/07/replication.html

If you don't need the replication of your data, then place the following property in your hbase and hadoop config files.

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
```